# Best way to replace all spaces, symbols, numbers, uppercase letters from a string in actionscript?

Tags: string, apache-flex, actionscript-3

What would be the best way to simply take a string like

```
var myString:String = "Thi$ i$ a T#%%Ible Exam73@";
```

and make `myString = "thiiatibleeam";`

or another example

```
var myString:String = "Totally Awesome String";
```

and make `myString = "totallyawesomestring";`

In actionscript 3 Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Extending @Sam OverMars' answer, you can use a combination of String's replace method with a Regex and String's toLowerCase method to get what you're looking for.

```
var str:String = "Thi$ i$ a T#%%Ible Exam73@";
str = str.toLowerCase(); //thi$ i$ a t#%%ible exam73@
str = str.replace(/[^a-z]/g,""); //thiiatibleexam
```

The regular expression means:

```
[^a-z] -- any character *not* in the range a-z
/g     -- global tag means find all, not just find one
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the regex you're looking for:

```
[Bindable]
var myString:String = "Thi$ i$ a T#%%Ible Exam73@";
[Bindable]
var anotherString:String = "";
protected function someFunction():void
{
    anotherString = myString.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, "");
    anotherString = anotherString.toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive what your looking for is:

```
var myString =  str.replace("find", "replace");
```

or in your case:

```
str.replace("$", "");
```

also, it might be:

str.replace('$', ' ');

//EDIT
How about:

```
 var mySearch:RegExp = /(\t|\n|\s{1,})/g;

 var myString =  str.replace(mySearch, "");
```

Comment: if i had to guess, if i did `str.replace("$", "");` it would only find an replace dollar sign symbols... I'm curious if there is a way to simply replace ALL possible symbols, spaces, uppercase letters, and numbers.

Comment: Thanks Sam H, beat me to it :)