# Remove some special character "[ ]" from a string

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm new to flex coding, for example if I have a string like "[123-456],[456-789]"
 and I want to remove all the "[" and "]" which result in:

"123-456,456-789"

can string.replace() or trim() do the job for me?
tried several times still fail

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031341/best-way-to-replace-all-spaces-symbols-numbers-uppercase-letters-from-a-strin

Answer (score 1):

In this case string.replace() should do the job!
Please see the [documentation for String.replace()](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#replace())

```
  var st: String = "[123-456],[456-789]";
  var p1: RegExp = /\[|\]/g;
  st = st.replace(p1, "");
  trace(st) //"123-456,456-789"
```